# how to pass SUBREPORT_DIR in jasper report

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, jasper-reports

I am using *JasperReports* as a reporting tool for Web Application. (JSP + Servlets)

I have developed a `Report` named `Cust` which has `Sub Report` named `CustSub`. I am trying to deploy this report on tomcat server (located on different machine).

There is parameter in `Cust` called `SUBREPORT_DIR` which has a value `"H:\\reports\\CustomerReport\\"`, this configuration works when I run the reports from `local tomcat server`, but when I try to run this report on `remote tomcat server` then it gives the following exception.

```
Resource Not Found, CustSub.jasper
```

So I think it is not finding the `Sub Report` named `CustSub`.

I tried using following two parameters for `SUBREPORT_DIR`, but it is not working.

```
SUBREPORT_DIR = "./"
AND
SUBREPORT_DIR = "com/mycomp/myapp/reports/"
```

So how should I pass `SUBREPORT_DIR` to `Sub Report` named as `CustSub`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to upload this subreport on the JapserReport server.

Steps to upload.

1:-Start JasperReport server and right click on the any directory where you want to save the subreport.

2:- Then "Add resource" then "File" and then "JRXML", browse subreport and give any name.

3:- Open iReport and go to main report and from palette drag "Sub report" and browse subreport from your machine.

4:- Add parameters in case you have .

5:- Select subreport and go to property section and "Sub report expression" property, edit and change the expression like "repo:/path of subreport jrxml in jasperreport